# FormatException in while loop c#/asp.net mvc application

Tags: c#

What is the problem with this conditional loop:

```
 while (System.IO.File.Exists(relPath)){ ... }
```

It trows an exception when it starts:

> Exception Details: System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be
>   greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument
>   list

The relPath string value is a "/Temp/pdfs/file.ext".
Any help?

Comment: @SLaks Check post update. Thank you for your attention

Comment: Is that line 605? If so, your build is probably out of date.

Comment: What's the `StackTrace` in the exception? (not the call stack where the debugger stopped)  Also, please don't HTML-escape code on SO; see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: @SLaks I´ll fix my post, Line 605 is the catch part of the try catch exception. "trow e". What you mean my build is out of date?

Comment: **Never write `throw e`**; it destroys the stack trace.  (which is why you have no idea what the problem is here)  Instead, write `throw;`, or get rid of the stack trace entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The System.FormatException is thrown because a substitution marker was not found in the argument list. If more arguments were provided, the program would not throw an exception.

My answer is copied from [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/formatexception), which provides sample code and shows the simple fix.

Comment: It is a while condition.... does not make sense. It is a function that returns true if file exist or false in case it does not.